# An edit to .master file broke my SharePoint Site, where can I look to restore the site?

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7, master-pages

I was trying to install Google Analytics in my site and I made quite the lazy move. Since I wanted the code to be inserted into the header of my site, I went to one of my files in the root of my site called root.master. This is the .master file that is referenced in all my site pages.

I simply copied and pasted the Analytics tracking code into that root.master file. The site is now broken! I tried deleting the code I put in. I also created a back up of the file before I did any work in it. I tried restoring that file from the backup. I also tried to reset the file to the site definition. No luck.

I'm not sure what the issue is or where to start! All I did was add the analytics code, nothing else. Can someone help me get this site live again?

The error message that displays is:

Sorry, something went wrong
The base type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebsiteCore.RootMaster' is not allowed for this page. The type Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebsiteCore.RootMaster, Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebSiteCore, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

Here is the root.master file that I edited:

```html
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebSite.Controls" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebsiteCore" %>
<%@ Import namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebsiteCore.Controls" %>
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Spx.WebsiteCore.RootMaster"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html dir="<%=Loc.ContentDirection %>" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <%=TitleAndMetaHtml %>
 <%-- The part of CSS that does not change for different themes --%>
 <Shared:ResourceIncludeControl runat="server" FileName="/_layouts/15/#LCID#/wh/stylesV2/masterroot.css" IsLocalized="false" ResourceType="CSS" />

 <%-- Required for table support --%>
 <Shared:ResourceIncludeControl runat="server" FileName="/_layouts/15/#LCID#/wh/stylesV2/tables.css" IsLocalized="false" ResourceType="CSS" />
 <Shared:ResourceIncludeControl runat="server" FileName="_layouts/15/#LCID#/wh/stylesV2/spxpubc2.css" IsLocalized="false" ResourceType="CSS" />

 <%-- Accessibility --%>
 <Shared:ResourceIncludeControl runat="server" FileName="/_layouts/15/#LCID#/wh/stylesV2/accessibility.css" IsLocalized="false" ResourceType="CSS" />
 
 <%-- Theme-specific CSS --%>
 <% if (isByosActivated) { %>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ServerRelativeUrl%>/_protected/theme.css" />
 <% } else { %>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ServerRelativeUrl%>/<%=FileManager.ResourceFolderValue%>/theme.css" />
 <%} %>
 <% if( customCssEnabled){ %>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ServerRelativeUrl%>/<%=FileManager.ResourceFolderValue%>/custom.css?lm=<%=customCssModifiedDate %>" />
 <%} %>
 <%=GetStyleHtml()%>

</head>
<body class="<%=Loc.ContentDirection %>">

<form id="IWS_WH_Elem_Form" runat="server">
 <div class="s4-notdlg">
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:this.href='#mainContent';" class="ms-SkiptoMainContent" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,maincontent_accesskey%>" runat="server"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
 </div>

 <table cellspacing="0" class="MS_MasterFrame" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td id="IWS_WH_Elem_GlobalLinks" class="MS_MasterGlobalLinks">
    <%=GetGlobalLinksHtml()%>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
   <td id="IWS_WH_Elem_Header" class="MS_MasterHeader">
    <%=GetHeaderHtml()%>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="<%=GetTopNavStyle()%>">
   <td id="IWS_WH_Elem_TopNav" class="MS_MasterPrimaryNav">
    <%=GetTopNavHtml()%>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%"> <tr>
    <td id="IWS_WH_Elem_LeftNav" nowrap="true" class="MS_MasterLeftNav" style="width:<%=GetLeftNavWidth()%>" >
     <%=GetLeftNavHtml()%>
    </td>
    <td class="MS_MasterBody">
     <a name="mainContent"></a>
     <div id="IWS_WH_Elem_Content" class="MSC_Body">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="IWS_WH_CPH_Content" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr></table>
   </td>
  </tr>
<% if (footerEnabled)   { %>  
  <tr>
   <td id="IWS_WH_Elem_Footer" colspan="2" class="MS_MasterFooter">
    <div class="MSC_FooterFrame">
     <span id="IWS_WH_Elem_FooterLinks">
      <%=GetFooterLinksHtml()%>
     </span>
     <div id="IWS_WH_Elem_FooterText" class="MSC_FooterText">
      <%=GetFooterText()%>
     </div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
<%} %>
 </table>
</form>

<%=RootMaster.GetFCProScript()%>
<!-- CXNID=5426436&Code=C2 --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you make: checkout, check-in, publish, approve of master page ?

Comment: @Max, I have tried to checkout, and check-in. However, I cannot find where I would publish and approve. I can't find the option to publish this file anywhere, on SharePoint Designer or Online. Could the problem be that my site is too old?

Comment: What Sharepoint version do you have ? Anyway master page are under version control, restore previous version and publish and approve new page. You can publish the master page with sharepoint designer and approve the item opening the list with browser.